# how to implement a read-only table in Swing GUI?

Tags: swing, scala, user-interface

I want to display my data in a table using scala GUI. But I need the contents of the table are read only. I know there is class Table(mutable) and ListView (read-only) in scala GUI.
My problem is I do not know how to combine them.
Thanks

Comment: I assume this is Swing. If so, the technique is not Scala-specific.

Comment: Implement an AbstractTableModel, and override isCellEditable() to return false. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.coderanch.com/t/334323/GUI/java/create-read-JTable which says

> a JTable has a model behind, a TableModel. You can either implement this or you extend from the DefaultTableModel. Anyway, there is a function isCellEditable(int row, int col). This function should return false in every case, then your table is not editable, but selectable.
>   Ta have a good starting point, you should read the Table section of the Java Tutorial of SUN.

The Java tutorial being referred to here is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).